# Apache Sling: unresolved package after Installing SlingShot sample bundle

Tags: osgi, sling

I am Unable to run slingshot sample , apache sling i have followed these steps 
Click [here](https://builds.apache.org/job/sling-samples-1.6/org.apache.sling%24org.apache.sling.sample.slingshot/ws/README.txt)!
the package got installed but it didn't get activated. The detail collapsed view of bundle shows

org.apache.sling.api.resource,version=[2.2,2) -- Cannot be resolved

Answer (score 1):

Your bundle import org.apache.sling.api.resource,version=[2.2,2) was not resolved. 
Assuming that your sling installation is running, you should verify if the package org.apache.sling.api.resource is either not exported or exported in the wrong version. 
If the package is present then adapt your import.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't indicate how you built or started the Sling instance where you installed the Slingshot bundle.

I just tried with a Sling launchpad built from the [launchpad/builder](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/launchpad/builder) folder of the Sling source code, the [Slingshot bundle](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/samples/slingshot) starts without problems and the /slingshot/albums.html path mentioned in the sample's README.txt works.